# Call to a member function find() on boolean

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Использую библиотеку simple_html_dom. Считываю csv файл. Далее обращаюсь к колонке этого файла:

```
while (($info = fgetcsv($a, 0, ";") ) !== false){
    $html = str_get_html(str_replace('\n','', iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $info[5])));
    var_dump($html); exit;
```

На экран выводится `object(simple_html_dom)` с контентом.

Убираю строку `var_dump($html); exit;` и валится:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in file.php on line 14
```

И за ним:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in file.php on line 16
```

Вот строка 16:

```
$inline_images = $html->find('img');
```

Если перед ней ставлю:

```
var_dump($html->find('img')); exit;
```

То возвращает пустой массив и никаких ошибок.

Почему так?

Comment: если вы перед строкой с ошибкой вставляете `exit`, то чего удивляетесь, что ошибка исчезает?

Comment: @teran так я перед exit еще добавляю var_dump с тем же содержанием, что в строке которую убираю. На самом деле - не важно, если я сделаю var_dump($inline_images); exit; уже после нее то все равно ошибок не будет.

Comment: вы начните со строки 14. у вас в `info` нет индекса 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Во время ПЕРВОГО прохождения цикла значение которое берётся из массива `$info[5]`, существует, в результате когда Вы вставляете `var_dump($html); exit;` Вы делаете dump $html переменной и закрываете дальнейшую обработку. Результат: ошибок нет.

   1.1 Что происходит когда данную строку убираете. Начинается цикл заново и после выполнения функции `fgetcsv` присваивается новый массив в котором нет индекса 5!!! О чём сообщает данная ошибка `Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in file.php on line 14`
2. Функция `str_get_html` после выполнения в качестве результата возвращает `false`, так как какая-то из функций внутри возвращает данное значение (предположу что iconv не может преобразовать undefined в кодировку!). Результат: `$html` получает не объект а `boolean` значение, ну а из данного значения невозможно вызвать метод `find()` о чём сообщает вторая ошибка.
3. Причины. Косяк в разбиваемом файле через функцию `fgetcsv` (предположительно). Решение. Отследить на какой итерации происходит не корректная отработка и поправить файл.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($html){
  $inline_images = $html->find('a'); 
  echo $inline_images;
}
```